# Map as webview in Flutter

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, dart, flutter

Since the map plugins in Flutter are quite limited, I built a Angular app using [Angular Google Map](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/), and I'm trying to show it in my Flutter app through [this](https://github.com/dart-flitter/flutter_webview_plugin) web view plugin. 

This is what I get:
[image]
Basically seems that everything works, but it doesn't ask me for permissions so the map doesn't render.(It works fine in my browser)
This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

class WebMap extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new WebviewScaffold(
   url: "mysite.com",
   appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("Cerca sulla mappa"),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: I faced this issue with angular once and it was height problem. would you send me the link of your angular map? I just tested it with angular map demo and it worked.

Comment: Sure: https://numenu-1526397532752.firebaseapp.com. I just tried it in my phone browser and the pop-up shows. Height should be 100%

Comment: Dear,I think what you see is a sea near africa.zoom out and check again

Comment: Ehm no, I'm in Italy. If I use a normal browser it finds my position and sets a pin on where I am..

Comment: Did you try zooming out?I faced this blue screen with your sample. I believe when position is not available, it sets the center to that sea. When I don't give location permission to my browser, it show the blue screen also.

Comment: Yes, i zoomed out and i could see that it was centered on the equator. Why doesn't ask for permissions? Is It because JavaScript doesn't run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177434/discussion-between-yamin-and-andrea-grippi).

Answer (score 1):

I tried using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) but I encountered geolocation permission issues with Android. Here's an [open ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27472) on GitHub regarding the issue.

A workaround that I did was using [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) plugin and adding geolocation permission prompt.

```dart
InAppWebView(
  initialUrlRequest:
      URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('https://maps.google.com')),
  androidOnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt:
      (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin) async {
    return GeolocationPermissionShowPromptResponse(
      origin: origin,
      allow: true,
      retain: true
    );
  },
)
```